# How to retrieve the default checked checkbox value in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to set checkbox default ng-checked true. This is working but the problem is submitting after value not appearing.

This is my html markup

```
<html ng-app="plunker" >
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="test1" ng-model="input.item1" ng-checked="true"/> Testing</label><br />
    <input type="button" ng-click="submit(input)" value="Submit" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Scripting app file is

```
 var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
 app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.name = 'World';
 $scope.input = {};
 $scope.submit = function (data) {
 alert(data.item1);
 console.log($scope.input);
 };
 });
```

plunker link is http://plnkr.co/edit/mwdQF6Qqd4yw6hvLHGd6?p=preview

How to default and directly reviving checkbox value.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ng-init` that will initialize the model with `true`, setting `ng-checked` to true at first will not initialize the model value

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test1" ng-model="input.item1" ng-init="input.item1=true" />
```

here is the updated [pulnker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DKoj1ehMxsjAQF8Jridl?p=preview)

Comment: its glad to help you, accept the answer if u found the solution ;)